# Word VSTO Table of Contents

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto, office-interop, tableofcontents

I am trying to create a Word file using Interop.Word library. I wanted to add Main Page, TOC next and some Chapters, but i had problems with TOC. I cant create it in different paragraph. When i did it normal i have Range problems and 0x800A178C error. In addition when i update TOC it creates links to images and cells in table.

```
Word.Range tocRange = wordDocument.Range(ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
tocRange.InsertAfter("Table of Content");
object start = wordApplication.ActiveDocument.Content.End - 1;
object oUpperHeadingLevel = "1";
object oLowerHeadingLevel = "3";
tocRange.Font.Size = 12;
tocRange.Font.Name = "Times New Roman";
tocRange = wordDocument.Range(ref start, ref oMissing);
Word.TableOfContents toc = wordDocument.TablesOfContents.Add(tocRange, ref oTrue, ref oUpperHeadingLevel, ref oLowerHeadingLevel, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
                                                                                       ref oTrue, ref oTrue, ref oMissing, ref oTrue, ref oTrue, ref oTrue);
```

Thank you for any advices.

Now i tried that

```
        //First|Main Page
        Word.Paragraph firstPageLogoParagraph = wordDocument.Content.Paragraphs.Add(ref oMissing);
        Word.InlineShape inlineShape = wordDocument.InlineShapes.AddPicture(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"..\..\Resources\logo.jpg", ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
        inlineShape.ScaleHeight = (float)300.00;
        inlineShape.ScaleWidth = (float)300.00;
        firstPageLogoParagraph.Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = Word.WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphCenter;
        firstPageLogoParagraph.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();
        //First|Main Page Title
        Word.Paragraph firstPageParagarph = wordDocument.Content.Paragraphs.Add(ref oMissing);
        object firstPageParagraphStyle = Word.WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleTitle;
        firstPageParagarph.Range.set_Style(ref firstPageParagraphStyle);
        firstPageParagarph.Range.Text = "\nWojskowa Akademia Techniczna" + softEnter + "im. Jarosława Dąbrowskiego" + softEnter + "w Warszawie";
        firstPageParagarph.Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = Word.WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphCenter;
        firstPageParagarph.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();
        firstPageParagarph.Range.InsertBreak();

        //Second Page|TOC Page
        object tocStart = wordApplication.ActiveDocument.Content.End - 1;
        Word.Range tocRange = wordDocument.Range(ref tocStart, ref oMissing);
        tocRange.InsertAfter("Spis treści\r");
        Word.TableOfContents toc = wordDocument.TablesOfContents.Add(tocRange, ref oTrue, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oTrue, ref oTrue, ref oMissing, ref oTrue, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
        //tocRange.InsertBreak();

        //Some paragraph
        //Add Paragraph after TOC
        Word.Paragraph firstParagraph = wordDocument.Content.Paragraphs.Add(ref oMissing);
        firstParagraph.Range.Text = "Rozdział 1";
        object firstParagraphStyle = Word.WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleHeading1;
        firstParagraph.Range.set_Style(ref firstParagraphStyle);
        firstParagraph.Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = Word.WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphLeft;
        firstParagraph.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();

        //Add Text after Paragraph 1
        Word.Paragraph firstParagraphText = wordDocument.Content.Paragraphs.Add(ref oMissing);
        firstParagraphText.Range.Text = "To jest tekst pod rozdziałem 1. Taki tekst wstawiłem pod tym tekstem.";
        object firstParagraphTextStyle = Word.WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleNormal;
        firstParagraphText.Range.set_Style(ref firstParagraphTextStyle);
        firstParagraphText.Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = Word.WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphJustify;
        firstParagraphText.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();
        //firstParagraphText.Range.InsertBreak();

        toc.Update();
```

but i have an error, COM Object was deleted....

I cant put pageBreak and update TOC at the end. I dont know why.

Answer (score 0):

`range.InsertAfter`, just like `range.Text`, do not insert a line break after your text. This is why you need to add `\r` after your text.

Change

```
tocRange.InsertAfter("Table of Content");
```

to

```
tocRange.InsertAfter("Table of Content\r");
```

The `Range` errors that you are getting are self explanatory: you're using invalid ranges. Assuming that you want to add the *Table Of Contents* at the start of the document, use this

```
    Word.Range tocRange = wordDocument.Range(0, 0);
    tocRange.InsertAfter("Table of Content\r");
    object start = tocRange.End - 1;
    object oUpperHeadingLevel = "1";
    object oLowerHeadingLevel = "3";
    tocRange.Font.Size = 12;
    tocRange.Font.Name = "Times New Roman";
    tocRange = wordDocument.Range(start, start);
    Word.TableOfContents toc = wordDocument.TablesOfContents.Add(tocRange, ref oTrue, ref oUpperHeadingLevel, ref oLowerHeadingLevel, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oTrue, ref oTrue, ref oMissing, ref oTrue, ref oTrue, ref oTrue);
```

Comment: I dont want to add TOC at the start the document but i want that it should be situated at second page. In addition heading level not works properly.

Comment: My recommendations still stand. Add `\r` at the end of a paragraph's text and make sure that when using Ranges you do not overwrite previous defined content.